# Accessing the elements of a sorted list with split()

Tags: python

I have created a sorted list of strings using

```
sorted_list=[[int(name.split("_")[-1]), name] for name in string_list]
```

The output looks like

```
[[0, 'str_0'], [1, 'str_1'], [2, 'str_2'], [3, 'str_3']]
```

How can I access the second element in each pair? I want to do

```
for the_str in sorted_list[1]:
    with open(the_str) as inf:
```

But is not valid and I get this error `ValueError: Cannot open console output buffer for reading`

How can I fix that?

Comment: you're calling `open` on the integer `1`. Perhaps you don't intend this?

Comment: I expect to see `the_str` as str_0, str_1, ...

Comment: but you see why it isn't as such? `sorted_list[1]` is the 1th element of `sorted_list` not the the 1th element of every sublist therein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted this:

```
for pair in sorted_list:
    with open(pair[1]) as inf:
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
for the_str in list(zip(*sorted_list))[1]:
    # code here
```

or just:

```
for val in sorted_list:
    the_str = val[1]
    # code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over the list, you get one pair after the other. You can split each pair in its parts in the `for` clause and leave the rest of your code as is:

```
for the_num, the_str in sorted_list:
    with open(the_str) as inf:
```

Answer (score 0):

The nesting of brackets says that there is a list of lists nested in sorted_list[0], so you need to dereference that first. You want sorted_list[0][i][1].